# Sort data according to sequence of keys in a slice Go

Tags: mysql, sorting, go, slice

I work with Go and MySQL database. Assume I have a slice of string like this: `[]string{"b", "c", "a"}` and I want to have final data like this:

```
[]Student{
    Student{ID: "b", Name: "Ben"},
    Student{ID: "c", Name: "Carl"},
    Student{ID: "a", Name: "Alexander"},
}
```

When I want to build MySQL query, is using `ORDER BY FIELD(id,'b','c','a')` an efficient way? Or if I don't use it, I will have code like this:

```
keys := []string{"b", "c", "a"}

...

students := make([]Student, 0)
for rows.Next() {
    s := Student{}
    err := rows.Scan(&s.ID, &s.Name)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    students = append(students, s)
}

mStudents := make(map[string]Student, 0)
for _, v := range students {
    mStudents[v.ID] = v
}

finalData := make([]Student, 0)
for _, v := range keys {
   if _, ok := mStudents[v]; ok {
       finalData = append(finalData, mStudents[v])
   }
}
```

But I think that's a very inefficient way. So, is there another way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MySQL's `ORDER BY FIELD(id,'b','c','a')` is efficient and there's nothing wrong with it if you don't mind having to extend the query and having your logic in the query.

If you want to do it in Go: Go's standard lib provides a [`sort.Slice()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice) function to sort any slice. You have to pass a `less()` function to it which must tell how 2 elements in the slice correlate to each other, if one is less than the other.

You want an order designated by another, sorted `keys` slice. So basically to tell if one student is "less" than another, you need to compare the indices of their keys.

To avoid having to linear-search the keys slice each time, you should build a map of them:

```
m := map[string]int{}
for i, k := range keys {
    m[k] = i
}
```

And so the index that is the base of the "less" logic is a simple map lookup:

```
sort.Slice(students, func(i, j int) bool {
    return m[students[i].ID] < m[students[j].ID]
})
```

Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rk-P3ZwNxSh).

Comment: so, which one might be more efficient? order it directly in MySQL or using `sort.Slice()`?

Comment: @RiefSapthana Sorting with the query will most likely be faster. Sorting in Go gives you more control and flexibility. Use whichever you like.

Comment: Use the best tools for the task at hand. You're already using SQL, so leverage it's capabilities and it'll simplify your client-side code.